# Conda gives InvalidArchiveError for qt6-main - seeking backwards is not allowed

Tags: python, conda, pyside6

I'm trying to install PySide6, which requires `qt6-main`, using Conda. During the install using the command

```bash
conda install qt6-main -c conda-forge
```

I get the error:

```
InvalidArchiveError('Error with archive C:\\Users\\Username\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\qt6-main-6.4.2-hc84ccb7_3.conda.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message was:\n\nfailed with error: seeking backwards is not allowed')
```

I have tried and this happens for versions 6.4.2 to 6.4.0. Is this a problem with Conda, with the archive or with something else?

Comment: What version of Conda? Did you try deleting the file from the package cache and reinstalling? Since this has to do with the `.conda` format, you may want to update `conda-package-handling`, e.g., `conda update -n base conda conda-package-handling`.

Comment: Try cleaning your conda package cache with `conda clean -a`

Comment: Yes, I tried deleting the downloaded file.

`conda` and `conda-package-handling` are both up to date (version 23.1.0 and 2.0.2 build py39haa95532_0 resp.)

Comment: I can't replicate any decompression issue: `wget https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/qt6-main/6.4.2/download/win-64/qt6-main-6.4.2-hc84ccb7_3.conda` and then `cph x qt6-main-6.4.2-hc84ccb7_3.conda` work fine. Using `conda-package-handling=2.0.2` on **osx-64**.

Comment: For me, your `cph` command gave more insight: It threw the error `File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\tarfile.py", line 2252, in makelink
    os.symlink(tarinfo.linkname, targetpath)
OSError: [WinError 1314] Dem Client fehlt ein erforderliches Recht: '..\\lib\\qt6\\bin\\qmake.exe' -> 'D:\\username\\temp\\qt6-main-6.4.2-hc84ccb7_3\\Library\\bin\\qmake6.exe'` this exception is handled in the tarfile script, but during the handling, the exception from the title comes: ` File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\tarfile.py", line 515, in seek raise StreamError("seeking backwards is not allowed")`

Comment: So the script can't generate the symlinks it wants to, and during the exception something else happens. I was able to extract the package without the error as admin, but that workaround shouldn't be needed - all the rest of Anaconda works fine as a normal user

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, before uninstalling/reinstalling(and updating) *Anaconda3*.
Now, I'm getting something different, but still with the same "smell":

```
(base)
capnf@DESKTOP-G84ND7C MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub/PyBERT (master)
$ conda build --python=3.9 --numpy=1.23 -c dbanas -c defaults -c conda-forge conda.recipe/pybert/
Adding in variants from internal_defaults
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from internal_defaults
Adding in variants from config.variant
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from config.variant
Attempting to finalize metadata for pybert
INFO:conda_build.metadata:Attempting to finalize metadata for pybert
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
INFO:C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\utils.py:rm_rf failed for C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.9.16-h6244533_0\.cph_tmphkgup82v
INFO:C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\utils.py:rm_rf failed for C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.9.16-h6244533_0\.cph_tmpxz2l6rsx
{Many more similar lines omitted for brevity.}
BUILD START: ['pybert-4.0.5-np123py_1.tar.bz2']
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
INFO:C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\utils.py:rm_rf failed for C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\pkgs\ca-certificates-2023.01.10-haa95532_0\.cph_tmpc_tze6iu
INFO:C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\utils.py:rm_rf failed for C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\pkgs\ca-certificates-2023.01.10-haa95532_0\.cph_tmptnnun2p2
{Many more similar lines omitted for brevity.}
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not remove or rename C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\pkgs\qt6-main-6.4.2-he04816f_2\.cph_tmp8tthp3vm\pkg-qt6-main-6.4.2-he04816f_2.tar.zst.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
INFO:C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\utils.py:rm_rf failed for C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\pkgs\pooch-1.4.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0\.cph_tmpse2dlzdg
INFO:C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\utils.py:rm_rf failed for C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\pkgs\pooch-1.4.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0\.cph_tmpfv2cch54
{Many more similar lines omitted for brevity.}

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\conda-bld\pybert_1676055211232\_h_env


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    appdirs:             1.4.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0
    asttokens:           2.0.5-pyhd3eb1b0_0
    backcall:            0.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
    blas:                1.0-mkl
{Many more package version specifiers omitted for brevity.}
{Solve appears to have succeeded.}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-build-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\cli\main_build.py", line 496, in main
    execute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\cli\main_build.py", line 485, in execute
    outputs = api.build(args.recipe, post=args.post, test_run_post=args.test_run_post,
  File "C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\api.py", line 186, in build
    return build_tree(
  File "C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\build.py", line 3091, in build_tree
    packages_from_this = build(metadata, stats,
  File "C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\build.py", line 2131, in build
    create_build_envs(top_level_pkg, notest)
  File "C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\build.py", line 2011, in create_build_envs
    environ.create_env(m.config.build_prefix, build_actions, env='build',
  File "C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\environ.py", line 910, in create_env
    execute_actions(actions, index)
  File "C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 86, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\plan.py", line 324, in execute_actions
    execute_instructions(plan, index, verbose)
  File "C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\plan.py", line 535, in execute_instructions
    cmd(state, arg)
  File "C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\instructions.py", line 67, in PROGRESSIVEFETCHEXTRACT_CMD
    progressive_fetch_extract.execute()
  File "C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 664, in execute
    raise CondaMultiError(exceptions)
conda.CondaMultiError: Error with archive C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\pkgs\qt6-main-6.4.2-he04816f_2\.cph_tmp8tthp3vm\pkg-qt6-main-6.4.2-he04816f_2.tar.zst.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:

Can't create '\\?\C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\pkgs\qt6-main-6.4.2-he04816f_2\Library\bin\windeployqt6.exe'
```

My system specifics:

- Dell XPS15 7590 32GB Windows11 Home

```
(base)
capnf@DESKTOP-G84ND7C MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub/PyBERT (master)
$ python --version
Python 3.9.13
(base)
capnf@DESKTOP-G84ND7C MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub/PyBERT (master)
$ conda --version
conda 22.9.0
(base)
capnf@DESKTOP-G84ND7C MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub/PyBERT (master)
$ conda list anaconda
# packages in environment at C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
anaconda                  2022.10                  py39_0
anaconda-client           1.11.0           py39haa95532_0
anaconda-navigator        2.3.1            py39haa95532_0
anaconda-project          0.11.1           py39haa95532_0
```

I can't get *Anaconda Prompt* to launch, either as Admin. or regular user.
So, I can't try that experiment.
And `sudo` doesn't work in `MINGW` on Windows.
So, I can't tell if it's a permissions thing. :(

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on Windows with up-to-date `conda` and `conda-package-handling`. Works fine on Linux.

I filled a bug at https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/12369

Answer (score 0):

While waiting the feedback of [issue filed by Nicolas](https://github.com/conda-forge/qt-main-feedstock/issues/125) , I tried conda install pip first and then pip install pyside6.   It shows in conda list and the packages are also under venv's site-packages.  I am using that as work around for the time being..FYI.